# NEO4j 3.0 retrieve data between certain period

Tags: neo4j

I'm using NEO4J 3.0 and it seems that HAS function was removed.
Type of myrelationship is a date and I'm looking to retrieve all relation between two dates such as my property "a" is greater than certain value.

How can I test this using NEO4j
Thank you

[EDITED to add info from comments]

I have tried this:

```
MATCH p=(n:origin)-[r]->()
WHERE r>'2015-01'
RETURN AVG(r.amount) as totalamout;
```

I created relationship per date and each one has a property, `amount`, and I am looking to compute the average amount for certain period. As example, average amount since 2015-04.

Comment: Can you add what queries you've tried? Also, have you read through the Neo4j development guide to familiarize yourself with the latest Cypher syntax? If you plan on using Neo4j beyond this, unless you get up to speed with the current version of Cypher, you're likely to ask more questions that the documentation can more easily answer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the issue raised by your first sentence: in neo4j 3.x, the `HAS()` function was replaced by `EXISTS()`.

[UPDATE 1]

This version of your query should work:

```
MATCH p=(n:origin)-[r]->()
WHERE TYPE(r) > '2015-01'
RETURN AVG(r.amount) as totalamout;
```

However, it is a bad idea to give your relationships different types based on a date. It is better to just use a `date` property.

[UPDATE 2]

If you changed your data model to add a `date` property to your relationships (to which I will give the type `FOO`), then the following query will find the average amount, per `p`, of all the relationships whose `date` is after `2015-01` (assuming that all your dates follow the same strict `YYYY-MM` pattern):

```
MATCH p=(n:origin)-[r:FOO]->()
WHERE r.date > '2015-01'
RETURN p, AVG(r.amount) as avg_amout;
```

Comment: I have tried this : 
`MATCH p=(n:origin)-[r]->() WHERE r>'2015-01' RETURN AVG(r.amount) as totalamout; `

I created relationship per date and each one has a property : amont and I4m looking to compute the average amount for certain period. As example, average amount Since `2015-04`

Comment: @MAYA Adding extra emphasis to cybersam's suggestion NOT to use a date string as the relationship type. If there are relationships that aren't date strings, then you may be comparing strings to date strings without realizing it, which may give you the wrong answers. For example, `return 'abd' > '123' as result` returns true, which could surely mess up your queries. Please capture the date as a property on the relationship instead, so your comparisons between relationship dates are always explicit.

Comment: I did this as a first modelisation but I got problem when to calculate total amount; my relationship was like that :
`'2015-01':{amount1:25, amount2:30}`